# Unity 17.04 Desktop Launcher problem for Terminal

Tags: unity, launcher, 17.04

I have just installed the final 17.04 Release.  Having problems with the Unity Launcher (not Dash, don't use that), *compared to what has always worked* in 16.04 & 14.04.

[To create a shortcut on Launcher I always run the program first from the shell, then when it's running I right-click its icon in Launcher and **Lock to Launcher**: if that is not the right way to do things let me know.]

Having run `term` and locked it to Launcher, the right-click menu offers **Terminal**, but no longer **New Terminal** as it used to.  Since *obviously* I will want multiple terminal windows, where has that option gone/how do I restore it?

EDIT:

To be clear, I am finding the **New Terminal** is missing no matter which way I lock the icon from.

I have discovered `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop`.  It includes line:

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity7;
```

In 16.04 that line was:

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
```

If I change line to remove the "`7`" (and remove locked icon and re-lock) I now get **New Terminal** again on right-click.  However, there is something odd, because although I can open a new terminal now from that icon, it launches a single new icon for the new terminal and that one does not offer **New Terminal**.

I *think* this is the area of difference from old behaviour, anyone care to explain?  (I hope new Unity has not removed **New Terminal** deliberately and wants you to middle-mouse-click instead?)

Comment: Remove its local launcher in `~/.local/share/applications`, log out and back in, run it from Dash and lock it again. The issue with your method is that Unity creates a new launcher locally instead of a copy from `/usr/share/applications`. Will post as answer later, I am in far far away atm.

Comment: @Jacob There is no local entry there to delete; and running from Dash makes no difference.  I am updating my question with more information.

Comment: Seems like it is a confirmed [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1681523), no solution yet

Comment: Good --- it's not just me!  I think this one will bite a lot of people on the behind.  I have posted my workaround at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1681523/comments/4.  I am marking this answer as "Accepted".

Comment: Yep, you are not alone :),  I am waiting for a solution too, thanks for your workaround.

Comment: Another workaround is offered at https://askubuntu.com/questions/908201/how-to-restore-open-new-terminal-by-right-click-in-unity - This may be a duplicate question as well, and this off-topic closed question was posted first.

Comment: The workaround there is the same as mine above.  With the same quirky behaviour.  This question got marked off-topic & closed when I said I was raising an error on Launchpad above!  I did think others would encounter this issue....

Comment: I also got negative reputation when they marked it off-topic :(  So it's best not to raise a question here if it turns out to be a bug in Ubuntu !